# How to write bare doxygen without source code?

Tags: doxygen

I'm going to write documentation for some script API bindings (Lua actually), so there's no source code at all. How can I do that?

I've tried to write bare doxygen like this:

```
\page My API document

\class BindedClassA
\brief descriptions on it

\var member1
\brief ssssssss

\fn bindedMethod1(arg1, arg2)
\brief xxxxxxx
\param arg1 yyyyyyy
\param arg2 zzzzzzz
\return wwwwww
```

It won't work at all. Actually it seems you must specify a language for every doxygen input file via `EXTENSION_MAPPING`.

Then I tried to put things in a fake C++ file that have no source code but only comments:

```
/**
 *\page My API document
 **/

/**
 *\class BindedClassA
 *\brief descriptions on it
 **/

/**
 *\var member1
 *\brief ssssssss
 **/

/**
 *\fn bindedMethod1(arg1, arg2)
 *\brief xxxxxxx
 *\param arg1 yyyyyyy
 *\param arg2 zzzzzzz
 *\return wwwwww
 **/
```

It generates document for BindedClassA, but only have brief description, no members o method documents were generated.

It seems the structure in source code plays critical role for Doxygen working properly, but I have no source at all.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What setting are there in your doxygen configuration file different from the standard settings (`doxygen -x Doxyfile` in the newer versions of doxygen). Note `\func` is not a doxygen command, maybe you meant `\fn`. You will probably need some dummy source code and also use the commands like `\defgroup` etc.

Comment: Did you google for e.g. "lua doxygen" ? (I see https://github.com/alecchen/doxygen-lua/tree/master/example, is very old and I don't know the quality)

Comment: @albert it's a typo, in my actual code it is `\fn`. I'm using doxygen version 1.8.13. When processing the bare document, I specified it as `INPUT`, and all other configs are default.

Comment: What is the extension used? 1.8.13 is quite old (December 2016), the current version is 1.9.1

Comment: @albert I'm not using extensions. The doxygen I installed is inside WSL Debian buster.

Comment: doxgen has the possibility to use "filters" so that languages (as lua) that are not directly supported can be documented by transforming the code (for doxygen) in something doxygen understands. I don't directly see a way to document without some dummy code / some "prototypes", commands like `\fn` try to place the out of place documentation with the relevant source.